# filter function in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to pick up the target name using automatic variable.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
dummytgt: $(OBJ)/tier.o
$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(filter $@,$(SOURCES)).c -o $@
```

I do not want to mention the filename as input but would want to use the filter function to get the .c file which is same as target name. make throws an error no input files

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to have a look at how *make* parses this:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
dummytgt: $(OBJ)/tier.o
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(filter $@,$(SOURCES)).c -o $@
```

First off,
it will read the makefile, defining and expanding macros as it goes.

- `SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)` means that `${SOURCES}` is a lazy variable with definition `$(wildcard *.c)`.
  Lazy? Yes, these *recursive* variables (as the *make* manual has it) only expand their right-hand side when they are themselves expanded.
- *Make* needs the dependencies as it reads the file, so `$(OBJ)` is expanded.
  Let's assume that the expansion of `${OBJ}` is `objs` (say).
- The shell command block remains as a single lazy variable.
  It's important to note that these are *not* expanded until *make* decides that it wants to build `dmmytgt`.

You could have written this to exactly the same effect:

```
dummytgt: objs/tier.o
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(filter $@,$(wildcard *.c)).c -o $@
```

For this fragment to work,
the file `objs/tier.o` must already exist.
Let's assume it does.

*Make* now has all it needs to build `dummytgt` (according to your makefile),
so now it expands the command block.

- `$(wildcard *.c)` expands to `1.c 2.c` (say).
- `$@` is `dummytgt`
- `$(filter dummytgt,1.c 2.c)` is of course empty (and always will be!)
- `${GCC}` is `gcc` (say)
- `${CFLAGS}` is empty (say)

Thus the shell gets

```
gcc  -c .c -o dummytgt
```

Presumably *gcc* complains that there is no file called `.c`.
The resulting error stops *make*'s execution.

A few thing not to like here:
`$(wildcard )` is only for hacky one-liner makefiles IMHO.
`dummytgt` requires `objs/tier.o`, but its build instructions never reference it.
Your `$(filter )` always expands to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(filter $@.c,$(SOURCES))
```

But I don't see why you don't use

```
$@.c
```

Or better still, make it a prerequisite.